# Getting EXIF data from photos using filepicker.io

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to get EXIF data, specifically geo location information from uploaded photos. Is there any easy way of doing this using the filepicker.io api?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we don't currently process EXIF data or expose it via the filepicker.io API. It's in our internal tracker, but no ETA as of yet.

Comment: Hi Brett just wanted to check to see if there was any updates about the EXIF data processing from filepicker?